# Creating an array of strings - c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
char str[1000], *arr;
int i = 0,len,counter=0,j=0;
arr = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char*) * 1000));
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    str[i] = getchar();
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        str[i] = '\0';
        arr[j] = malloc(sizeof(char)*counter);
        strcpy_s(&arr[j], counter * sizeof(char), &str[i - counter]);//i dont know why but this line does me some problems
        j++;
        counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
}
}
```

I am trying to create an array of strings but the strcpy is not letting me and i do not know why. help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Compiling with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` and letting us know what the problems are is a great start

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x0FE2170D (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000061.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: how do i use wextra?

Comment: type of `arr[j]` is `char`. Also `str[i] != '\0'` is using uninitilize value.

Comment: Do you understand data types?

Comment: yes i do understand data types

Comment: why just don't you use a char ** as destination ?

Comment: Did you read the compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because `str[i - counter]` is a `char`, not a pointer. You need to write `&str[i - counter]` or `(str + i - counter)`.

See the signature of [strcpy_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy): `errno_t strcpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src);`

Comment: did as you said and now there is an assertion failure

Comment: @EladRaif "_an assertion failure_": more details please.

Comment: @MichaelWalz.Expression:(L"Buffer is too small" && 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int count_spaces(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (str == NULL || strlen(str) == 0)
      return (0);

    int i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
          count++;
        i++;
    }

    return count++;
}

char **get_strings(char *str)
{
    if (str == NULL || strlen(str) == 0)
      return NULL;

    char **dest;
    if ((dest = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (count_spaces(str) + 1))) == NULL || (dest[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1))) == NULL)
      return NULL;

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            dest[k][j] = '\0';
            j = 0;
            dest[++k] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
        }
        else
          dest[k][j++] = str[i];

        i++;
    }

    dest[k + 1] = NULL;
    return dest;
}


int main()
{
    char **dest;
    dest = get_strings("this is a test for stackoverflow");

    int i = 0;
    while (dest[i] != NULL)
      printf("%s\n", dest[i++]);
}
```

here is a quick (non-perfect) example to do it with char **

you give a string as parameter and the function will store each segment using space as delimiter in a char **

you can print it as i did in the main. Don't forget to free when you're done